# Build Jenkins: Android project with dependencies

Tags: android, jenkins

I use Jenkins as an integration server. And, I try to build an Android project which contains many project dependencies without using Maven. So I want to ask how can I do this task?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a ["free-style software project"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project).  You'll need to create an Ant build file and add your dependencies manually.

You could also look into using [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to manage your dependencies if you don't want to use Maven.